# Class diagram as a for-loop

Tags: class, for-loop, uml, diagram

I was wondering how to represent a for loop as a class diagram.
So basically a for-loop consists of a Set, (at least) one bound variable/iterator and the body (cf. picture).

So obviously the containment rules are easy, but how to express that connection between the variable i and the set and the possible connection between the variable i and the body?

ie:

```
for(int i = 0; i< set.length; i++){
// some statements referencing the iterator
// i.e. set[i] = i;
}
```

[for-loop class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOmgA.png)

Also I know that there are better diagrams in UML to describe a for loop (like an activity diagram for example) but i m interested how the dependency between the iterated set and the iterator could be expressed as a class diagram.

Comment: This is completely broken. I guess you should go back and do some basic reading. Or maybe I just don't get what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it the right diagram to use ?**

A [class diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html) shall represent structural relations between classes/types.  It can also represent constraints.

But a class diagram can't represent the control flow (e.g. conditionals, loops, etc...).  For these, you should consider [activity](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html) or [sequence](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) diagrams with [combined fragments](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html).

Nevertheless, your question highlights an interesting question:  *how to represent the dependency between iterator and iterated container ?*

**Iterators in class diagrams**

One way of representing the relation is certainly to look at the [iterator design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/iterator-pattern.html), which uses a [navigable association](http://www.modernanalyst.com/Careers/InterviewQuestions/tabid/128/ID/1807/What-is-a-navigable-association-in-UML.aspx) to the container.

However not all iterator implementation can navigate back to the container (e.g. an iterator to a linked list might not know the linked list as a whole but only the current element).  In this case you would use a [simple dependency](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html) (doted line with an arrow) from the iterator to the container.  You can make the meaning explicit with the `<<use>>` stereotype:  the iterator depends somehow on the structure of the iterated container.

If needed you could also use [UML template](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html) for the container and the iterator to show the type of the objects in the container/interated on.

**Abstracting a for loop into a calss ?**
Your diagram attempt suggests that you could be tempted to use a [command design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html) to abstract some operations to be done on a container (the container would be the receiver).  In this case, the body would not be another class on its own, but would be a method that would be overriden in a concrete derived command.

However, your intent is not fully clear to me, and there could be more appropriate design patterns to consider as well.